# Why can't I get attributes in saml onelogin?

Tags: python, saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

I did everything according to this manual .
https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/python
But I didn 't succeed .
I get an error.

> Errors: invalid_response
> There is no AttributeStatement on the Response

my settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/phH5s.png

```json
{ [ {] 
  "strict": true, 
  "debug": true, 
  "sp": { 
    "entityId": "http://siteproxy.ru/metadata/", 
    "assertionConsumerService": { 
      "url": "http://siteproxy.ru/?acs", 
      "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    },
    "singleLogoutService": {
      "url": "http://siteproxy.ru/?sls",
      "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
    },
    "NameIDFormat": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress",
    "x509cert": "",

    "privateKey": ""
  },
  "idp": {
    "entityId": "https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/918d180a-a86a-406f-88db-a4dc44d9c150",
    "singleSignOnService": {
      "url": "https://supertestapp-dev.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/918d180a-a86a-406f-88db-a4dc44d9c150",
      "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
    },
    "singleLogoutService": {
      "url": "https://supertestapp-dev.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/1668425",
      "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
    },
    "x509cert": "MIID7jCCAtagAwIBAgIUA0HawEb/ruz25jOJEj9cBcKdcKswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwSzEWMBQGA1UECgwNTW9ub3NuYXAgSW5jLjEVMBMGA1UECwwMT25lTG9naW4gSWRQMRowGAYDVQQDDBFPbmVMb2dpbiBBY2NvdW50IDAeFw0yMDEwMTIxMjI0MzVaFw0yNTEwMTIxMjI0MzVaMEsxFjAUBgNVBAoMDU1vbm9zbmFwIEluYy4xFTATBgNVBAsMDE9uZUxvZ2luIElkUDEaMBgGA1UEAwwRT25lTG9naW4gQWNjb3VudCAwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC+kpEaaUr3zbftURxz1c05hVHMdCn4IlZ+fV5TmX0y3JgTCN0H5Y0cXrgCVmY3LvdcqjL8LEXlbsZyvMnzXLIChcXQoAp5JSMtKdl+KG4j6aPi37MWlxADV7bJoAtclxJayhO0AldIz3wdAhzfYkbQctYuamnm7Y6Qpyd3elctYNajVYVIxrYwWzMQjwdapDGfRsjK509u1fyYxkxwEnvfVDG2e77TJLD4SY+4bkHiMXVQf87E19xZtmT0tW7ANCCrOpn4D2Uf7OFUJRYHLPRJA+BD9AVjRbWnobcRd1wM69c+24z5G4S6ly4T0PqwM/Spms33lRqOE6uYacmW6i07AgMBAAGjgckwgcYwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUVAaut68tuEQGq9fYYzN4NpNqYS8wgYYGA1UdIwR/MH2AFFQGrrevLbhEBqvX2GMzeDaTamEvoU+kTTBLMRYwFAYDVQQKDA1Yw25vc25hcCBJbmMuMRUwEwYDVQQLDAxPbmVMb2dpbiBJZFAxGjAYBgNVBAMMEU9uZUxvZ2luIEFjY291bnQgghQDQdrARv+u7PbmM4kSP1wFwp1wqzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAEghILiZNTJJ8T+8iyOQ6JWtO5LYgpr/rjDJxxyL8hBCtpLHO4ruM5ZBLTytZBTbLJVc0fBUtivRXlCypJuEtCueH7mHf9YwEFsTHZvmY9Ywy9cDa3GydygugLPpABYzgDXRxcps7N4xcs83/4m5uZBFcQCu5YwPsUwZHwOX+CjIyPPs5lZd4ybBEviykDDXkE1LPaQtFhXHJ1X6OChG6QTxtVZWfVyDr8Js1fSxBU2mnEEhCBMQZoFe8aViahUqrCjKm429oHk1ibgTcZ23rIxY9ZaB/88PV+vfrbj1BJGs0MfStuX7YwgAiUSynbg3cw/tnj/9e1Sk9wDEhYEf+k8="
  }
}


{
    "security": {
        "nameIdEncrypted": false,
        "authnRequestsSigned": false,
        "logoutRequestSigned": false,
        "logoutResponseSigned": false,
        "signMetadata": false,
        "wantMessagesSigned": false,
        "wantAssertionsSigned": false,
        "wantNameId" : true,
        "wantNameIdEncrypted": false,
        "wantAssertionsEncrypted": false,
        "allowSingleLabelDomains": false,
        "signatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
        "digestAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256",
        "rejectDeprecatedAlgorithm": true
    },
    "contactPerson": {
        "technical": {
            "givenName": "technical_name",
            "emailAddress": "technical@example.com"
        },
        "support": {
            "givenName": "support_name",
            "emailAddress": "support@example.com"
        }
    },
    "organization": {
        "en-US": {
            "name": "siteproxy",
            "displayname": "siteproxy",
            "url": "http://siteproxy.ru"
        }
    }
}
```

I realized that if I pass
"wantAttributeStatement": false,
It looks like the registration will take place. but I won't be able to get email and other attributes.

Im use python3-saml  https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml/issues/301

Comment: You can try adding "wantAttributeStatement": false and see if it resolves the issue. In any case you should still be able to send Email and other attributes from OneLogin to your application

Comment: I know I can pass "wantAttributeStatement": false, but I get the same error. And even if I pass "wantAttributeStatement": false, how can I get this email and other attributes in the python3-saml library https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml/issues/301 ?